# Is it possible to inject a bean into a View?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing a custom View and want to inject a Configuration for the Freemarker Template Engine as following, but *configurer* is always null.

```
@Component
public class WkHtmlToPdfView extends AbstractView {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().toString());

@Inject
private FreeMarkerConfigurer configured;
```

The Bean is correctly configured, because in a Controller it is correctly injected:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public class DashboardController {

@Inject
private FreeMarkerConfigurer configured;
```

The Configuration is nothing special as I think:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xxxxxx.yy.repository" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxxxxx.yy")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() throws IOException, TemplateException {
    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory factory = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory();
    factory.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:WEB-INF/templates");
    FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    freemarker.template.Configuration config = factory.createConfiguration();
    config.setIncompatibleImprovements(new Version(2, 3, 20));
    config.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    config.setLocale(Locale.GERMANY);
    config.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
    config.setObjectWrapper(new BeansWrapper());
    result.setConfiguration(config);
    return result;
}
```

Is it not possible to inject Beans into Views? What am I missing? 
Thanks for your help!

**EDIT 1**

My View is in a sub package view. And I have a AppConfig, which i missed to mention. 
Actually it looks like this.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxxxxx.yy" }, excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Controller.class, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION) })
public class AppConfig {

}
```

But if I set

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxxxxx.yy", "com.xxxxxx.yy.view" }
```

it works!
Can you explain me what makes the difference? I thought sub packages would be scanned as well. And extending ComponentScan in WebAppConfig has no effect - why?

Comment: What are you using as `ViewResolver` ?

Comment: Is the view in a package scanned by @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxxxxx.yy")